# Существует ли число которое не может обработать современный компьютер? Какая у него длина?

Tags: математика, железо, калькулятор

Возможно ли обработать число длиной 1 МБ? Если да, то как?

*обработать - например сложить или умножить.

Сколько времени это займет?

Comment: Ограничено ресурсами. Что вы понимаете под "обработать"? Например, получить сумму двух чисел? Да запросто - лишь бы они помещались на диске, а операционная система позволяла их читать... Как? А как вы работаете с числами на бумаге, "в столбик", например? Вот примерно так же... Так что все зависит от ресурсов - чтоб была возможность считать и записать эти числа.

Comment: Существует. Например, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: 64-битный процессор работает с 64-битными целыми числами. Всё, что больше, реализуется ручками, как и обработка любых данных. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Статья "Universal Limits on Computation" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0404510.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну раз вас интересует время... вот вам (очень тупой прямолинейный) пример для суммирования двух чисел с миллионом знаков каждое.

У меня считает примерно за 4 миллисекунды...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    const int N = 1000000;
    char * a = new char[N+1];
    char * b = new char[N+1];
    char * s = new char[N+2];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand()%10 + '0';
        b[i] = rand()%10 + '0';
    }
    a[N] = b[N] = 0;
    s[N+1] = 0;

        int carry = 0;
        for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            int c = a[i] - '0' + b[i] -'0' + carry;
            if (c > 9)
            {
                carry = 1;
                c -= 10;
            }
            s[i+1] = c + '0';
        }
        s[0] = carry+'0';

        cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Измерение времени я для простоты выбросил. Генерация чисел и вывод в измеряемое время не входили.

Если взять оптимизированную библиотеку, скажем, `cpp_int` из Boost - то суммирование она выполнила за примерно 300 мкс, а умножение - за 20 секунд. Вот вывод был куда дольше :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;

using large = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    const int N = 1000000;
    char * a = new char[N+1];
    char * b = new char[N+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand()%10 + '0';
        b[i] = rand()%10 + '0';
    }
    a[N] = b[N] = 0;

    large al(a), bl(b);
    large sum, prod;
    sum = al + bl;
    prod = al * bl;

    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << sum << endl;
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << prod << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете реализовать такую математику используя массивы, где каждая ячейка является разрядом. Сложение и умножение в таком случае будет реализовываться поразрядно, как в столбик.

Можете поискать реалиазации в свободном доступе. Примеры:

- https://github.com/Kegdan/LongArithmetic
- https://github.com/greg-kargin/DM43